# Multiple websites all sharing the same layout

Tags: html, htaccess, website-design

I have a client that has a website. He owns around 200 domains, and wants each domain to contain content from the main website.

The header, footer, and navigation bars will remain the same for each domain, but the actual page content will vary (obviously duplicate content issues, open to suggestions)

He wants each individual page to be its own separate domain, rather than an URL within the main domain: `page1.example`, `page2.example`, etc. and NOT `example.com/page1.html`, however the file is actually hosted at `example.com/page1.html` and all links will direct to `example.com/whatever` accordingly.

What would be the best place to start learning on how to do this, and what concerns/considerations should be taken into mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you're describing are [microsites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsite).

You might find that the reaction to this idea is not very good. See this for more as to why:  [Microsites. A Bad Idea Most of the Time](http://www.ninebyblue.com/microsites-a-bad-idea-most-of-the-time/), as referenced by Matt Cuts in his video discussing them here:  [What's your opinion on microsites?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NmiSDxR68Nk)

As covered in those, a few microsites may not impact your SEO results, but several hundred might. I would advise your client that he's better off building up his main site instead of spreading authority out over multiple sites, that might appear "spammy", and could be impacted by Google's Panda update which combats "domain farms". See this for more on that:  [Google Forecloses On Content Farms With “Panda” Algorithm Update](http://searchengineland.com/google-forecloses-on-content-farms-with-farmer-algorithm-update-66071)

It might prove difficult to maintain all these sites as well (e.g., submitting each to search engines, managing links, avoiding domain expiration's, etc...), which might be better spent on improving the main site.

So my answer here is that the concerns and considerations might outweigh the motivation to do this, and the need to figure out how to approach forwarding/redirects.

Comment: each site is intended to be a single page site, targetting a specific city. Thanks for the links however, I will definitely forward them!

Comment: Your client may indeed change his/her mind based on the above, since using numerous domains has become ineffectual as of late. If they don't, you would want use 301 redirects from each domain to the respective pages on the main site (e.g., `page1.com` -> `site.com/page1.html`) to avoid duplicate content. See this for more:  [Google Webmaster Tools - 301 redirects](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en). Alternatively, you could use [iframes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp), but they might not benefit your SEO for the main site.

Comment: we have been 301 redirecting, however for google adwords, it rejects all campaigns due to the domain on the ad not matching the end location.

Comment: I see - so it sounds like might have to host the page for each domain under itself instead of hosting it at `site.com` (e.g., with vhosts). AdWords might also reject sites with too little content as well, if your single page sites are too thin. Maybe using subdomains might be the best course considering everything.